# Does the language $\{(1^n2^n)^t \mid t,n\ge0\}$ contain the string $121122$?

Tags: formal-languages, context-free

Does the Context Free Language $\{(1^n2^n)^t \mid t,n\ge0\}$ contain the string $121122$? Does $t$ fix $n$? I think the string belongs to this language.

Comment: Why do you think so? What is the specific issue/question/doubt yoiu are having?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$t$ and $n$ are independent numbers. Any string in the language consists of $t$ units, where each unit consists of $n$ $1$s followed by $n$ $2$s.  In particular, then, the string generated by any choice of $t$ and $n$ contains $tn$ $1$s and $tn$ $0$s.

Comment: FWIW, unwary authors sometimes intend that the copies of $n$ are independent as well (which is a pain to denote formally). We have, of course, no way of knowing what the OP resp. their source intend, and you answer the literal question aptly.

Comment: @Raphael This is a bit like question: "What's a cat?" answer: "It's an animal that says miaow" comment: "Some people use the word 'cat' to refer to dogs." Well, great. Those people are objectively completely wrong. This isn't a valid alternative reading and I think that adding a comment drawing attention to this mistake (which I, personally, have never come across) just causes confusion. We know that either the OP's source intends what I said or is wrong.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Agreed. "We know that either the OP's source intends what I said or is wrong", if for no other reason than every string in the language is determined by a *single* pair $(n,t)$. Every now and then one of my students gets this wrong, as did the OP.

Answer (score 1):

The way language is defined 121122 is not an acceptable string. 1212 or 11221122 is acceptable string.

The string 121122 belongs to another similar language $L_1$ where
$L = \{1^n2^n\  |\  n \geq 0 \}$,
$L_1 = L^*$. This might be the source of confusion.

Comment: Your $L_1$ is *not* the language from the question. I don't know what purpose it serves; there are uncountably-infinitely many languages that contain this given string.

Comment: I don't disagree, I was just pointing to what I thought was the source of confusion